# PHP Regex many matches

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, configuration-files

I have a Drupal [config](https://pastebin.com/WZkRjE47) file that contains sets of lines like this:

```
 *     'driver' => 'mysql',
 *     'database' => 'databasename',
 *     'username' => 'username',
 *     'password' => 'password',
 *     'host' => 'localhost',
 *     'prefix' => '',
```

(2 times actually) and it also has a set of lines like this:

```
    array (
      'database' => 'dba',
      'username' => 'admin',
      'password' => 'admin1234',
      'host' => 'localhost',
      'port' => '',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => '',
    ),
  ),
);
```

(Occurs only 1 time in the file)

The difference, as shown, is that there is no star mark * (Comments tags) on the lines that I need to target/match.

I'm using the following regex, but it is not returning the desired string.

```
preg_match("#'password' => '(.*?)'#isU",$file_source , $pass);
```

This is my attempted regex pattern demo: https://regex101.com/r/lDA4y4/2

What I want is the password value: `admin1234`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* hack at your config file with regex...

([here is the demo](https://regex101.com/r/XJVN9t/1) for the optimized pattern: `/^ {6}'password' => '\K[^']*/m`)

However, I worry that you are completely missing the point/beauty of having a `.php` config file.

If you just `include` (or `require`) the file in scripts that need it, then you will have direct and clean access to all of the variables and configurations that it holds.  This means after:

```
include('config.php');  // you may need to modify the path for your case
$db=$databases['default']['default'];  // I recommend this line to simplify variable access
```

You will be able to access variables like this:

```
$db['database']; // = dba
$db['username']; // = admin
$db['password']; // = admin1234
$db['host']; // = localhost
$db['port']; // [empty string]
$db['driver']; // = mysql
$db['prefix']; // [empty string]
```

As a consequence, you will also benefit from the other non-commented declarations within.

```
$update_free_access = FALSE;
$drupal_hash_salt = 'N5wfuEGIDhz8C8LuelMlQjkosDt2Avr9ygNciIbmAqw';
ini_set('session.gc_probability', 1);
ini_set('session.gc_divisor', 100);
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 200000);
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 2000000);
$conf['404_fast_paths_exclude'] = '/\/(?:styles)|(?:system\/files)\//';
$conf['404_fast_paths'] = '/\.(?:txt|png|gif|jpe?g|css|js|ico|swf|flv|cgi|bat|pl|dll|exe|asp)$/i';
$conf['404_fast_html'] = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-1.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><title>404 Not Found</title></head><body><h1>Not Found</h1><p>The requested URL "@path" was not found on this server.</p></body></html>';
```

If you don't want any of these other declarations, then you comment them out or manually create a new config file that contains only your desired declarations (additionally you could simplify the `$databases` array structure).

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the line without the *, just check for the line starting with whitespace:

```
preg_match("/^\s+'password'\s=>\s'(.+)',/im", $source, $matches);
$pass = $matches[1];
```

So basically with `^\s+'password'` you define that from the start of the line `^` until the string `'password'`, it can only contain whitespace characters `\s+` (1 or more).

See: https://regex101.com/r/KG4inA/2